# Weight issue with layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

This question is connected with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164814/imageview-weights-in-linearlayout). I haven't found the solution in correct way - I get screen width programmatically and add margins to ImageView in this way.

Now I have new issue.
Here is layout where weights are working correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_dir_fl_time_go"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_dir_fl_time_go_back"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_dir_fl_duration"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem.Isdirect"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_dir_fl_is_direct"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem.Isdirect"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_ret_fl_time_go"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_ret_fl_time_go_back"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_ret_fl_duration"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem.Isdirect"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_ret_fl_is_direct"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem.Isdirect"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_airline_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_airline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_buy"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And almost the same layout where the weights are not working! Again! (The result is the same as in my previous question, see in the beginning of the post).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_airline_name"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_airline_plus_number"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_duration"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_date"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_time"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_city"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"
            android:text="@string/txt_loading"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_city_iata"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_date"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_time"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_city"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"
            android:text="@string/txt_loading"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_city_iata"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I wonder if someone could help me..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_airline_name"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_airline_plus_number"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_duration"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_date"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_time"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_city"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"
            android:text="@string/txt_loading"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_start_city_iata"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_date"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_time"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_city"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"
            android:text="@string/txt_loading"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt_go_finish_city_iata"
            style="@style/WrapContent.ListItem"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please try this